# How to turn on computer programmatically using phone in Android

Tags: android

I'm new in Android programming and there is this project I'm working on to be able to turn on my computer using my phone. I have written my codes where by when an item in a list-view is clicked, it will fetch mac address and use it to turn on computer. The problem is that, the packet is never sent, I'm using Emulator. I have tried to search solutions in Google but couldn't find enough break through. Really need your help.

Here are my codes:

```
    package black.cheetah.blackcheetah;


import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ComputerTurnOnList extends Activity {
public static final int PORT = 9; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_computer_turn_on_list);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll()
            .build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
 }

 public void buttonClick(View view) {
String broadcastIP = "192-168-43-171";
String mac = "3C-97-0E-82-3D-BD";
Log.d("Read mac= ", mac);
Log.d("Read ip=", broadcastIP);
ComputerTurnOnList.wakeup(broadcastIP, mac);
  }


 private static byte[] getMacBytes(String mac) throws IllegalArgumentException {
     Log.d("GetMacBytes", "method started");
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     byte[] bytes = new byte[6];
        String[] hex = mac.split("(\\:|\\-)");
        if (hex.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address.");
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
                Log.d("GetMacbytes", "calculated");
                Log.d("GetMacBytes (bytes)", new String(bytes));
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e("GetMacBytes","error");
        }
        return bytes;
}


 public static void wakeup(String broadcastIP, String mac) {
     Log.d("wakeup", "method started");
if (mac == null) {
    Log.d("Mac error at wakeup", "mac = null");
    return;
}

    try {
        byte[] macBytes = getMacBytes(mac);
        Log.d("wakeup (bytes)", new String(macBytes));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[6 + 16 * macBytes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            bytes[i] = (byte) 0xff;
        }
        for (int i = 6; i < bytes.length; i += macBytes.length) {
            System.arraycopy(macBytes, 0, bytes, i, macBytes.length);
        }

        Log.d("wakeup", "calculating completed, sending...");
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(broadcastIP);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length,address,9);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.send(packet);
        socket.close();
Toast.makeText(null, "Time up! Couldn't find Computer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        Log.d("wakeup", "Magic Packet sent");
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("wakeup", "error" +  e.getMessage());
     }

 }

 }
```

When I run it here come an error:

```
    05-30 06:26:15.607: D/Read mac=(1755): XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/Read ip=(1755): xxx-xxx-xx-xxx
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/wakeup(1755): method started
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/GetMacBytes(1755): method started
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <����������
05-30 06:26:15.617: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.657: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <���������
05-30 06:26:15.657: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.657: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <�������
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <������
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <��=��
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacbytes(1755): calculated
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/GetMacBytes (bytes)(1755): <��=�
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/wakeup (bytes)(1755): <��=�
05-30 06:26:15.667: D/wakeup(1755): calculating completed, sending...
05-30 06:26:15.667: E/wakeup(1755): errorUnable to resolve host "xxx-xxx-xx-xxx": No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: The emulator is isolated from your local network and has its own address space. Check this: https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: I have tried to run it again and it gives me the android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: You cann't do network operations on the UI thread. You have to use an `AsyncTask`: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can send UDP via emulator or at least it is not that simple. Try it on your real device.

I got it working with this

```
public class WakeOnLAN {

    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 9;

    private static final String TAG = WakeOnLAN.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String MAC_REGEX = "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}";

    public static int sendPacket(String ipStr, String macStr) {
        return sendPacket(ipStr, macStr, DEFAULT_PORT);
    }

    public static int sendPacket(String ipStr, String macStr, int port) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (port < 0 || port > 65535) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Port must be in the range [0, 65535]. Magic packet is usually used on port 7 or 9");
        }

        byte[] macBytes = getMacBytes(macStr);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[6 + 16 * macBytes.length];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) 0xff;
            }
            for (int i = 6; i < bytes.length; i += macBytes.length) {
                System.arraycopy(macBytes, 0, bytes, i, macBytes.length);
            }

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipStr);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, address, port);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.send(packet);
            socket.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Wake-on-LAN packet sent.");

            return 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send Wake-on-LAN packet:" + e);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] getMacBytes(String macStr) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (!macStr.matches(MAC_REGEX)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address");
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[6];
        String[] hex = macStr.split("(:|\\-)");

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Should not happen, the regex forbids it, but it doesn't compile otherwise.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex digit in MAC address.");
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

And the Activity

```
public class WakeOnLanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private static final String TEST_IP = "192.168.1.255";
    private static final String MAC = "74:D4:35:E7:BA:DC";

    private Button btnSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wake_on_lan_demo);
        setWidgetConnections();
    }

    private void setWidgetConnections() {
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new WakeOnLanTask(TEST_IP, MAC, 9).execute();
            }
        });
    }


    class WakeOnLanTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        private String IP;
        private String MAC;
        private int port;

        public WakeOnLanTask(String ip, String mac, int port) {
            this.IP = ip;
            this.MAC = mac;
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... args) {
            return WakeOnLAN.sendPacket(IP, MAC, port);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }

}
```

Comment: @CondradMariki I don't know about your code, but I have put mine here. That one I am sure works.

Comment: Thanks Bojan, I'll try it in my device. And how does it work? I mean, I'm really confused with the need of ip address, as why do we need ip address if the system is off?

Comment: Acually the ip adress of my pc is 192.168.1.2, but you need the ip adress of the subnet, so always 255 at the end is ok. You can read the current IP of your phone and set the ip dynamically, I have not done that.

Comment: I did that with my codes. But I wonder why the packet isn't sent. How does the ip help to work computer?

Comment: I haven't tried your code, nor have I tried it so I don't know what the problem is. I have given you the code that works, try it out. The IP adress helps to determine to which subnet the packet should be sent, every device on that subnet receives the same message and then compares it's mac adress to the one in the packet, if it matches, it wakes up. Unix program wakeovelan does not need IP as it finds it on it's own, but if you want to wake up a pc in super subnet, that is bad... You cannot do it

Comment: Thanks Bro for clarification. I tried the codes, somethings occurred that didn't understand well. 1: The BaseActivity extended 2. The Utils bring me error, tried imports from android and java but couldn't find any. Am I missing something? Sorry, as I said new in this and really trying.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Those were the classes I used, I have replaced them with Android classes, see my edit.

Comment: I get the point Bro. That means I don't have to extend a class if I don't have any as you have.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the updated code. Use AppComaptActivity instead of BaseActivity and Log.d and Log.e instead of Utils...

Comment: I did. It wants me use AliasActivity instead of AppCompatActivity hence bringing errors in onCreate, needing to remove the override annotations and in super,setContentView and findViewById

Comment: just use a normal Activity if you still have problems. It really doesn't matter :D

Comment: You made me laugh.OK, Let me try again.

Comment: It worked brother. It worked. Packet was sent in Emulator never thought of that but it did. Now I'm going to try in my device to check the response.

Comment: What an excitement :D

Comment: I tried in my phone, the pc didn't wake. I put my Wireless MAC and static ip address of 192.168.43.255. Enabled wake on magic packet and wake on pattern match in both Boradcom 802.11n Network Adapter and Qualcomm Atheros AR8162/8166/8168 PCI-E Fast Erthernet Controller (NDIS 6.20). I'm in a wireless connection.

Comment: If you computer is on wifi, things change. You need to use WoWLAN standard instead of WoLAN. I don't know anything about that standard and I have never implemented it as I don't need it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Comment: I see. The drivers I'm using, only have those wake on magic packet and wake on pattern match. Let me find more about Wake On Wireless LAN especially for Qualcomm Atheros Driver. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi pal. Guess what, I tried. I found information about Wireless LAN, followed all the instructions but still no response. I'm using my college wireless as 'server'.

Comment: Well let me clarify how I did, may be I went wrong in some point. I installed the app in my phone with the 'install only once' selection, assigned a static ip address to my computer, configuring wake on wireless LAN, connecting my phone to the college wireless LAN, turn off the computer, run the app and boom, no response. So, is there any place I did wrong? Help please.